# How to solve if roles changed bot shows nickname updated

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
  if (!((String(oldMember.nickame)) == (String(newMember.nickname)))) {
    gwebhook.send({
      embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(newMember.guild.name, newMember.guild.iconURL({dynamic: true}))
      .setTitle('Member Nickname Update')
      .setColor("YELLOW")
      .addField('Before', String(oldMember.nickname), true)
      .addField('After', String(newMember.nickname), true)]
    });
  }
```

It gives logs even when role changed.

Comment: I sadly don’t have the answer to your question, but what I do know is that the String(user.nickname) casts are redundant. The data is already a string.

Comment: I had tried without String also same err

Comment: Voting to close as this issue was caused by a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is a simple typo. First, let's simplify your code removing all of those redundant and not-so-pretty `String()` casts:

```js
if (!(oldMember.nickame == newMember.nickname)) {
    gwebhook.send({
      embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(newMember.guild.name, newMember.guild.iconURL({dynamic: true}))
      .setTitle('Member Nickname Update')
      .setColor("YELLOW")
      .addField('Before', oldMember.nickname, true)
      .addField('After', newMember.nickname, true)]
    });
  }
```

That makes the code a lot easier to look at. And now the issue is obvious. You did `oldMember.nickame` instead of `oldMember.nickname` in your `if` statement. Since `oldMember.nickame` is `undefined` (as it is not an existent property of guild members due to the typo), it will always not be equal to `newMember.nickname`. Therefore, whenever a member is updated in any way (whether nickname change, role change, or any other member change), the code inside this `if` statement will always be executed. Just fix the typo and the code should work as expected:

```js
if (oldMember.nickname != newMember.nickname)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt notice that